# how to retrieve all information when coming back to the page previously visited

Tags: asp.net, .net

There are two pages page1.aspx and page2.aspx
page1 contains two tables.
after submitting page1 it redirects to page2. now when i'm trying to come back to page1 all data are gone. Is there a way to retrieve those data when coming back from page2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Session` dictionary to store data. If you are willing to change your page design then use `MultiView` and `View` [asp.net control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx), in that no need to [create two pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ek2z7fh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Well my page1.aspx have got 15 to 20 textboxes and 4 dropdowns, its really frustrating to add them in session . i have to check view as i hvnt used it yet. Any other ways to do this would be very useful.

Comment: If i use view and multiview i have to use it in same page as i have two pages. I m thinking of using querystring. which one would be quicker?

Comment: Do not use querystring if you want to write/store these data.

Comment: Then i have to do it in one page.Its like starting over again.. thanks anyways guys.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of links explain the behavior and how to use it.

[HTTP is a stateless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol).

[ASP.NET Web Forms has a few state management options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).